# ASP.NET MVC Model Binding returns null when model type is inherited from CollectionBase

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This is my model

```
public class MessageSetTypeCollection<T> : CollectionBase where T : MessageSetType, new()
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string[] Tags { get; set; }

    public MessageSetType this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return (MessageSetType)List[index];
        }
    }

    public void Add(MessageSetType value)
    {
        List.Add(value);
    }
}
```

This is my controller actions

```
public ActionResult TestAction()
{
    MessageSetTypeCollection<MessageSetType> Model = new MessageSetTypeCollection<MessageSetType>();
    Model.Add(new MessageSetType()
    {
        Alert = "test"  // Alert is a public property of the MessageSetType class
    });
    Model.Add(new MessageSetType()
    {
        Alert = "test2"
    });
    return View(Model);
}

[HttpPost]
public void TestAction(MessageSetTypeCollection<MessageSetType> Model)
{
    return;
}
```

In the view I've this code

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorFor(a => a[0].Alert)
    @Html.EditorFor(a => a[1].Alert)

    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

When I submit this form to the TestAction action, the inner list into the Model parameter has a Count of 0 elements. Why?

I've also tested this code with `List<MessageSetType>` model type instead of `MessageSetTypeCollection<MessageSetType>` and all works correctly. Where is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved inheriting the `MessageSetTypeCollection<T>` from `List<T>` instead of CollectionBase

```
public class MessageSetTypeCollection<T> : List<T> where T : MessageSetType, new()
{
    //Omissis
}
```

Comment: Yes, The issue is that `CollectionBase` is `abstract` and the `DefaultModelBinder` cannot initialize an instance of an abstract class (internally it uses `Activator.CreateInstance()`)

Answer (score 0):

Please see here source code for List:
http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs

The implementation is pretty different. You don't have a collection of type MessageSetType on which your indexer should work.

I think you can use source code of to adjust your model: MessageSetTypeCollection.